# Get specific data from excel spreadsheet and print/execute a command in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file that has a list of people, their address, phone numbers, message and many other columns. I need to create a loop that will check each cell value and print (later execute) specific columns.

[This is the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsfgS.png)

i need to print the following (for each line)

```
Hi {First Name},
{Message - Column}
```

once i have this right, I will need to execute the following for each line.

`client.send_sms({mobile number}, {message})`

I have this code currently but having problems understanding how to loop this into executing the client.send_sms.
thanks

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_loc = "C:/Users/jack/Downloads/text.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A,I,J")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check the value of each column (`row[0]` is the first column).

```
for row in open("file.csv"):
  name = row[0]
  msg = row[10]
  print('Name'+name +'  '+ 'Message:'+ msg)
```

Comment: thanks
i have added this code to my code as following:

```import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_loc = "C:/Users/jack/Downloads/text.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A,I,J")
#print(df)

for row in open("C:/Users/jack/Downloads/text.xlsx"):
  name = row[0]
  msg = row[10]
  print('Name'+name +'  '+ 'Message:'+ msg)```

but i get the following error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 22: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: The error accures because you are using an .xlsx file, change it to .csv

Comment: the code is looking for data in the rows but it is ignoring the columns.

this is what i am getting now
NameR  Message:
Name   Message:
NameJ  Message:R
Name   Message:
NameK  Message:&

thanks

Comment: Hi All
i think i was misunderstood and i am sorry for that.
what i need is a loop that will go trough the excel file and for each row will do the following:
client.send_sms("column number", "Messsage")
example:
client.send_sms("2124433555", "Did you get my voicemail")